# Rectangle collisions in Java and how do I use them properly?

Tags: java, libgdx, physics

Currently I have code that will detect the collisions of 2 Rectangles using `r1.overlaps(r2)` but I don't really know how to make the rectangles simply collide and stop moving(everyone has equal force theoretically) Currently I've played around with combinations of making one stop, reverse, or both but it always turns out buggy(whether the rectangles slowly morph together or just clump and stop moving).

Here is my collision statements ( they work)

```
public static void checkCollisions() {
        for(int i = 0; i < Map.enemies.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Map.players.size(); j++) {
                if(Map.enemies.get(i).body.overlaps(Map.players.get(j).body)) {
                    Map.players.get(j).hit = 1;
                    Map.enemies.get(i).hit = 0;

                }

            }
            for(int j = 0; j < Map.enemies.size(); j++) {
                if( i!= j && Map.enemies.get(i).body.overlaps(Map.enemies.get(j).body)) {
                    Map.enemies.get(j).hit = 0;
                    Map.enemies.get(i).hit = 0; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the Movement methods (same for both currently. 8 direction movement works perfect until we add in collisions and the boxes will not appreciate it.. `tick()` runs everytime the screen renders as well as `checkCollisions()`)

```
if(hit == 1) {
            double MoveX = 0;
            double MoveY = 0;


            if(degree >90 && degree < 270) MoveX-=1;
            if(degree < 90 || degree > 270) MoveX+=1;
            if(degree > 0 && degree < 180) MoveY+=1;
            if(degree > 180 && degree < 360) MoveY-=1;

            if(MoveX == 0) MoveY *=1.5;
            if(MoveY == 0) MoveX *=1.5;


            x--;
            y--; 
        }else if( hit == 0){
            double MoveX = 0;
            double MoveY = 0;


            if(degree >90 && degree < 270) MoveX-=1;
            if(degree < 90 || degree > 270) MoveX+=1;
            if(degree > 0 && degree < 180) MoveY+=1;
            if(degree > 180 && degree < 360) MoveY-=1;

            if(MoveX == 0) MoveY *=1.5;
            if(MoveY == 0) MoveX *=1.5;


            x += MoveX;
            y += MoveY;

        }
        hit = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is that 1.5  double math is wonky.  Multiply by 15 and divide by 10, or do things in a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider box2d? That would give you much more realism in your "recoil" from boxes colliding.

If you want to roll your own, consider:

I assume  by your API usage that your rectangles are axis aligned, so a collision defines a third rectangle C where A overlaps B. Find the centerpoint of this C, as well as A and B. You could move A's centerpoint, for example, back along the line defined by centerpoint A and centerpoint C. Do the same for B. You'll have to experiment with how much to move back, though. If you move until A and B's edges pass through centerpoint C, you should no longer have a collision.

That's an off the cuff, relatively simple algorithm. If you want something more realistic, I'd say go with box2d.

Comment: I've used box2d in the past but for this style of game I'm going for a more 2d top-down shooter feel so I didnt feel like it would be the way to go. And what youre basically saying is that I need to more or less, move A away from B in the direction A came from?

Comment: No, there's some pushback to B as well. It's a simple solution - basically split the difference and push them both back.